# A question about proving Rice's Theorem by reducing it to the Halting Problem

Tags: computability, undecidability, rice-theorem

I've read the definition for Rice's Theorem, here's the one from Wikipedia:

> In computability theory, Rice's theorem states that all non-trivial,
>   semantic properties of programs are undecidable.

The classical proof for proving Rice's Theorem is [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem#Proof_by_reduction_to_the_halting_problem), which is similar to [other sources](http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~acm/ricep.pdf).

However, I have a problem with this proof, made clear (hopefully) in the paragraphs following.

This proof goes like this:

> if we had an oracle for deciding these properties of program behavior, we would be able to use it to solve the Halting Problem, but the Halting Problem is undecidable, so an oracle for deciding these properties cannot exist either.

However, as far as I know, the impossibility of the Halting Program only occurs if the program checking whether something halts or not is trying to prove the hypothetical `does_it_halt(a, i)` wrong by using self-referencing tricks. But, in this proof, the oracle that is trying to decide the property is not trying to do that. So, it should be able to do its job without solving the Halting Problem.

I had some hope at the beginning that this proof may be wrong, but since it is apparently the "classical" proof for proving Rice's Theorem, I must be missing something. What is it that I am missing ?

Comment: Do you know what is the meaning of DECIDEing a problem using Turing machine?

Comment: @DsD I think I know. Care to elaborate ?

Comment: If you look precisely on its definition you'll find it there is no Turing machine for halting problem accept yes inputs and reject no inputs. Which means there can't be something (that computes) deciding Halting problem.

Comment: @DsD Could you elaborate further ? I don't see your point yet. If you are talking about that `does_it_halt(a, i)` function, it's a hypothetical function, not actual.

Comment: Deciding in Turing machines means you definitely accept yes inputs and reject no inputs. While there are Turing machines that accept yes inputs for halting problems certainly but for no inputs they may go on infinite loop.

Comment: @DsD I understand, but you could just check a program's syntax to get around that. The point which proves the undecidabilty of the HM is the contradiction example. If this has a connection I am missing to my original question, please tell me of it :)

Comment: you CAN'T just check a program syntax to decide whether it halt on its input or not (probably you can do it for some specific programs). You must RUN it on its input to see it it will halt and you'll never understand if the running of the program on that input goes on infinite loop.

Comment: @Ds_D Why wouldn't I be able to run an analysis on the program and its input and just decide if a loop will halt ? AFAIK such a thing good be achieved for many programs. Could you add an example where I wouldn't ? This is probably where I'm wrong. I will be going to sleep now, hopefully I will have an answer ere I wake up.

Comment: Are you comfortable with basic reduction proofs in computability? That would be the first step since this proof is a "meta proof" in a certain sense.

Comment: Of course there are examples! Try to write a program for Goldbach conjecture. I mean write a program using "for" loop for every  integer and check whether it satisfy Goldbach conjecture or not. If it satisfies then check the next integer and halt otherwise. If you can, just look  at this program's syntax, and decide whether this loops runs infinite time or it will eventually halt.

Comment: Rice's Theorem informally says that you can't decide about the language of a program (except those languages which we define using syntax, like codings of Turing machines with one transition rule) just by looking at its syntax.

Comment: @Raphael I am reading about it on Wikipedia and it seems to be pretty simple, but I guess I have a problem with that concept which would help me answer the question I've asked above ? Could you be more specific ?

Comment: @DsD Interesting, I would love it if you could sum up all of this and add it as an answer.

Comment: @DsD As an example of a more usual challenge, if one has a loop that depends on external data (say from an external server), one wouldn't be able to decide whether or not that one halts either, huh ?

Comment: It seems someone wrote an answer sooner than me which you've accepted. I just suggest you read relation  of halting problem and incompleteness of Godel for further reading and finding out why you can't decide halting problem.

Comment: @Ds_D I could not be more grateful for your help. But do you approve of the answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, as far as I know, the impossibility of the Halting [Problem] only occurs if the program checking whether something halts or not is trying to prove the hypothetical `does_it_halt(a, i)` wrong by using self-referencing tricks. But, in this proof, the oracle that is trying to decide the property is not trying to do that. So, it should be able to do its job without solving the Halting Problem.

The proof shows that, if we had a machine $M$ to decide a nontrivial semantic property, we can craft another machine $N$ to solve the Halting problem.

With "$N$ solves the Halting problem" we mean that $N$ can decide the termination of absolutely any other Turing machine, including those using "self-referencing tricks" -- no exceptions.

In a nutshell, "for all" means "for all". If we show that a machine decides a problem, then it must always do its job on all inputs. The mentioned proof crafts a machine $N$ which does not "decide the Halting problem, except for self-referencing cases" (whatever that might actually mean in formal terms). $N$ is proved to work "for all" inputs.

By the way, it's a common misconception to think that we actually detect when a program is "self-referencing", and that we could work around the impossibility of deciding the halting problem by weakening the goal to "decide whether $T$ halts on input $x$, as long as there is no self-referencing". What actually happens is that there are infinitely many machines $U$ equivalent to $T$ we could use for the "self-referencing", and
(by Rice!) deciding whether $T$ and an arbitrary $U$ are equivalent or not is impossible. No algorithmic "syntactic inspection" on two programs can hope to decide whether they are equivalent on all cases.

Indeed, at first the self-referencing trick looks as a quite unsatisfactory negative proof, making one think that it could be worked around easily by just excluding that case. However, it is far more general than it looks at first.

Comment: Thanks for answering! But in this line `The mentioned proof crafts a machine N which does not "decide the Halting problem, except for self-referencing cases"` Did you mean `which does` ?

Comment: `What actually happens is that there are infinitely many machines U equivalent to T we could use for the "self-referencing"` Could you elaborate or/and provide an example ?

Comment: @doubleOrt No, i mean "which does not (only) ..."

Comment: `However, it is far more general than it looks at first.` As in, more general cases of self-referencing, or other ways other than self-referencing, which make the Halting Problem impossible to decide ? I would be thankful if you could elaborate :)

Comment: @doubleOrt Given program $T$, you can generate a program $U$ which on input $n$ (natural) first checks if there is a counterexample to some complex theorem, say, Fermat Last Theorem with numbers $<n$. If there is one, the program behaves differently from $U(n)$, otherwise it behaves exactly as $U(n)$. Proving that $U$ is equivalent to $T$ requires proving that no counterexamples exist to the Fermat Last Theorem, i.e. proving the theorem itself. You can generate other examples replacing FLT with your theorem of choice.

Comment: @doubleOrt It's hard to see but there's no clearly defined notion of "self-referencing". Some cases may seem obvious, but if you try to formalize that, you'll always find a loophole. E.g. if $P$ is Java program, instead of passing $P$ to $P$ itself, we can pass to $P$ a Python interpreter $I$ (written in Java), which executes a Java interpreter (written in Python), which fetches its code from a base-23 number sequence, which happens to be an encoding of the original $P$ program. Since there's no way to sanely define "self-referencing", it's best to avoid using that notion.